# How to re-size images taken with Print Screen while keeping the original aspect ratio?

Tags: screenshot, screen-printing, scale

Say for instance I have pressed `Print Screen` and cut the following image:

[image]

Now I wish to scale this down to about 338 width and 338 px height. However when I do this in **Paint** (I know, noob program) I get the following result:

[image]

Which looks somewhat compressed and ugly.

So my question is: How would you go around doing stuff like this? Are there any free programs that can help you?

Comment: You simply need to scale **proportionally**.

Comment: The size you offer is not realistic! you clearly have a long rectangular image, the width is clearly much longer than the height! but the size you want is the same for both (338) which clearly a square! the image will be "squished" and thus produce the result you saw. Without cropping and losing some of the image, it cannot be a square! but if you want to keep the proportions as they are, then the above answer is correct. you only input the width size that you desire, and the height will be calculated automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to tell Paint to keep the ratio when scaling. This is what my paint (Windows 8) looks like, but there should be a similar command in yours if your OS is different:

[image]

If you need to work with images I suggest you download a copy of [**The Gimp**](http://www.gimp.org/). It's free, open source and quite easy to use. The same dialog as above in Gimp will look something like this. The little **chain icon** is the one that tells the re-size to keep proportions:

[image]

See the [image **source** and detailed **instructions** to re-size in Gimp](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11503.html).

Gimp has a lot of [**tutorials**](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/) worth checking as well.